# Will the standard library of C++11 have forward declaration headers?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, forward-declaration

In C++03 there are no `<vectorfwd>`-like files, while there is the `<iosfwd>` header. Will this change in the future?

It could be valuable to reduce dependencies and for better modularity.

UPDATE:

I have received an answer from the language creator: "*practically it's not possible to require this from all STL vendors*".

Comment: describe `lots of problems`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no new forward files, just the old `<iosfwd>`.

The complete I/O-system is large compared to a vector, so the advantage would perhaps not be that significant.

Comment: That's why I prefer QTL - I can write forward declaration for any template.

Comment: @Iakov : Why is that desirable?

Comment: See [Forward declarations in C++ - when it's matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028526/forward-declarations-in-c-when-its-matter)